# way to extract thumbnail with q value is over 5.0 in ffmpeg command?

Tags: ffmpeg, pictures, combine, frame, iframe

I edited question(thanks for advice.).
When I extract a thumbnail from ffmpeg, I can get a message like this in very end of message.

```
# ffmpeg -ss 600 -i /home/juneyoungoh/Videos/T30644_19_120412.ts.pac -vframes 1 -y /home/juneyoungoh/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.jpg
ffmpeg version git-2013-05-31-9d56ccf Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on May 30 2013 21:34:51 with gcc 4.6 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
  configuration: --extra-libs=-ldl --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-x11grab --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-version3
  libavutil      52. 34.100 / 52. 34.100
  libavcodec     55. 12.102 / 55. 12.102
  libavformat    55.  8.102 / 55.  8.102
  libavdevice    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
  libavfilter     3. 73.100 /  3. 73.100
  libswscale      2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
[h264 @ 0x32da920] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 0x32da920] concealing 742 DC, 742 AC, 742 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x32da920] left block unavailable for requested intra4x4 mode -1 at 0 5
[h264 @ 0x32da920] error while decoding MB 0 5, bytestream (4350)
[h264 @ 0x32da920] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 0x32da920] concealing 1174 DC, 1174 AC, 1174 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x32da920] left block unavailable for requested intra4x4 mode -1 at 0 18
[h264 @ 0x32da920] error while decoding MB 0 18, bytestream (1641)
[h264 @ 0x32da920] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 0x32da920] concealing 589 DC, 589 AC, 589 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x32da920] left block unavailable for requested intra mode at 0 9
[h264 @ 0x32da920] error while decoding MB 0 9, bytestream (2331)
[h264 @ 0x32da920] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 0x32da920] concealing 994 DC, 994 AC, 994 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x32da920] left block unavailable for requested intra mode at 0 22
[h264 @ 0x32da920] error while decoding MB 0 22, bytestream (269)
[h264 @ 0x32da920] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 0x32da920] concealing 409 DC, 409 AC, 409 MV errors in P frame
[mpegts @ 0x32d68a0] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5013333 microseconds
Input #0, mpegts, from '/home/juneyoungoh/Videos/T30644_19_120412.ts.pac':
  Duration: 00:59:01.21, start: 10.000000, bitrate: 2309 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Stream #0:0[0x200]: Video: h264 (Main) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p, 720x480 [SAR 8:9 DAR 4:3], 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.93 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x201]: Audio: aac ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 187 kb/s
Output #0, image2, to '/home/juneyoungoh/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.jpg':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf55.8.102
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 720x480 [SAR 8:9 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 29.97 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 -> mjpeg)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[h264 @ 0x32da920] Missing reference picture, default is 0
[h264 @ 0x32da920] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x32da920] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 0x32da920] concealing 686 DC, 686 AC, 686 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x32da920] left block unavailable for requested intra mode at 0 28
[h264 @ 0x32da920] error while decoding MB 0 28, bytestream (6046)
[h264 @ 0x32da920] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 0x32da920] concealing 139 DC, 139 AC, 139 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x32da920] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 0x32da920] concealing 830 DC, 830 AC, 830 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x32da920] left block unavailable for requested intra mode at 0 17
[h264 @ 0x32da920] error while decoding MB 0 17, bytestream (11936)
[h264 @ 0x32da920] concealing 634 DC, 634 AC, 634 MV errors in I frame
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=5.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.03 bitrate=N/A    
video:23kB audio:0kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead -100.091663%
```

I think this part "frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=5.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.03 bitrate=N/A " shows information of output file(In this case, jpg image file).

What I am seeking is the way to extract thumbnail from Video files, only case of "q >= 5.0".(I think this 'q' means quality. I knew there is an option 'q', but may be has different meaning)

1. I going to access certain point of Video via 'ss' option.
2. I will check this frame quality is over 5.0 or not.
3. If yes extract thumbnail, otherwise closest frame which has quality value over 5.0.

Can I do this with ffmpeg option + Linux commandline?

Comment: Please describe what you mean by "combining several frames as one". Perhaps you could show us an example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: @slhck I thought one picture(Video scene?) is consist of I+B+P frames. like end of this page(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter_frame). So I guess if can gather several frames and mixed up, can make clear picture. I guess...

Comment: When you extract an I-frame, you will always get a complete picture, because the frame does not depend on others. So your issue is that, even though you extract I-frames only, you get distorted images?

Comment: @slhck actually my problem is I can get Iframe pictures, but sometimes the output quality is so low. like this --> frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=1.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.03 bitrate=N/A.   How can I extract only over q=5.0?

Comment: @slhck Thanks before edit, my question is ambiguous:D Thanks for guiding.

Comment: Your question is now clear, but I'm not sure the q value in the output actually has an effect. For me it stays at `q=0` for all tests, even when setting `-q:v` for the output. What I'm just curious about is: why do you ask this? Are the thumbnails you get showing bad quality? Can you include an example of the thumbnails your command creates?

Comment: @slhck Actually I am trying to extract thumbnails from Videos which has DRM in it. The DRM company says that they did not scrambled Iframes, but I think it is not true.(because ffmpeg basically access to Iframes but Images are still crumble.) So I investigated what is deferent some picture crashed and not. And now I believe those messages(q=X.X) can be a clue. normally contents has 'q' value over 5.0 is pretty nice, even though DRM in it. So I need to find q > 5.0. Thanks for asking:D